# Are there benefits of having Ashwagandha / Withania somnifera as pre-workout supplement?

Tags: bodybuilding, testosterone, pre-workout

*Ashwagandha* is referred as one of the best T-Booster supplement as mentioned [here](http://www.anabolicmen.com/ashwagandha-testosterone/).

Also [Cellucor P6 T-Booster](https://www.cellucor.com/p6-red) has Ashwagandha in it.

My question is can i take *Ashwagandha* root/pills before workout? Will it improve the performance?

Comment: The close votes on this are ridiculous. How can you say it's unrelated to exercise when he specifically asks about the effects of using it as a pre-workout? Stop trying to close every question you don't understand!

Comment: I'd be careful.  Most of the studies you reference are pretty small in size.

Comment: I'd like to close it just because it opens the door to a lot of spam, but I won't vote against it.

Answer (score 1):

Ashwagandha (Withania somnifera) supplementation helps to have significant increases in muscle mass and strength and it is suggested to be taken twice a day, one right after you wake up and again one right before you go to bed (300 mg of starch or 300 mg of a high-concentration ashwagandha root extract). "Ashwagandha is a member of the family of herbs referred to as “adaptogens”. The term “adaptogen” is applied to a herb with phytonutrients that regulate metabolism when a body is perturbed by physical or mental stress, and help the body adapt by (a) normalizing system functions, (b) developing resistance to future such stress, and (c) elevating the body’s functioning to a higher level of performance"
Here is a good newly published article about it. [Examining the effect of Withania somnifera supplementation on muscle strength and recovery: a randomized controlled trial.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26609282). Besides, it is also good for [anxiety](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2729375/?tool=pmcentrez)

Comment: I'm not sure an 8 week study consisting of 57 participants shows much.  I'd rather see a much larger study over a number of months/years.

Comment: To make people to use it over months/years,by the way, would cause some ethical problems for the study. Besides, 8 weeks (for strength development) is enough period to test the effect of the treatment and 57 is a good sample size for a scientific study.

Comment: @rrirower - If you look, it was also untrained individuals, as their pre measurements were 79 lbs for bench press 1RM, and 60 lbs for 1RM leg extension. (interesting that the placebo group started out already lower than the treatment group). Theoretically treatment group gained 100 lbs on their 1RM bench max and 30 lbs on the leg extension. There wasn't any notice that they paid for the study, but a for profit company selling the extract supplied the extract for the study.

Comment: So, 8 weeks is sufficient time to determine the efficacy and safety of what could be considered a drug?  Not sure the US FDA would agree with that.

Comment: You may ask this question the the author and publisher or editor

Comment: @rrirover that is right, I am just talking about the study and outcomes

Answer (score 1):

Please be cautious when experimenting with Testosterone.  The body usually balances your increased T-levels with Estrogen, because too much testosterone can cause testicular cancer. There are estrogen blockers such as DIM that can be taken as part of your stack.  Again, use caution and do your research on Examine.com.  Look at the general ads on TV for law firms advertising their services, if you have ever used products such as Androgel etc.  There is a reason for those ads. If the reason for your post is that you feel like you're plateauing, look for other ways to exercise. Look up Weider principles, get more sleep/rest, but be careful when you mess with hormones.

Comment: Is there any basis to your advice (answer)?